# How to change the rootInterfaceController in watchOS6

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I am developing an independent app for Apple Watch. So after my short onboarding finishes there is no way to replace the rootController where the login page was displayed. Instead I can only modally or push a controller on the current view.

Since in independent apps there are situations where one may want to replace the view entirely.

Haven't found anything in the docs, can anybody point me in the right direction regarding the code or the way I should think about navigation in Apple Watch